# How to Deploy Git to Test/Production IIS Win 208/2012 Servers Ignoring certain folders

Tags: windows, git, iis, ssh, deployment

Apologies in advance if this question is simple or easily identifiable. I have searched here and on the web to find the answers but being new to Git I don't know the correct terminology or how to find my specific responses.

I have recently taken to using Git for version control on classic asp software being written. I am using VirtualBox for local testing but wish to figure out how to deploy the code from the repository (aws codedeploy) directly to the server.

The directory which the files are located, including the .git, .vagrant and website files are all located in the repository.

I would like to take only the files within the "website files" folder and deploy them to a directory on the remote IIS server (windows Server 2008 R2 for one project, windows Server 2012 R2 for another).

There are also uploaded files on the server which I would like to leave in place when doing the deployment as these files have been uploaded via the software (.pdfs).

**Do I pull the files from the repository (aws) to the server or do I push them from aws to the server?**

*It looks like my best option here is to install git on the server and pull the repository into the working directory.*

**how do I make the server only pull the files that I need?**

*Setup gitignore in the directories where I need to leave existing files or not take files at all.*

**How do I pull only the "website files" from the repository to the web server folder, or do I need to create a folder 1 above the application and make the application folder the "website files" folder?**

*This seems to be possible via svn, however it will be easier to grab the whole repository via a pull request and have the website application folder the one within the repo files as opposed to the level above.*

**I'm currently using the top level application folder name to determine which connection strings the software is to use, if the application folder name needs to be the same, I need an alternative way to make the software know which connection strings are to be used, any suggestions?**

*I'm still working on this, but if I name the folder that the repo resides in as the software name for this function, I should be able to use that so the website files can all have the same name, but the path further up can be the delimiter. Alternatively I could use the application ID, but on multiple systems there could be a clash.*

**Is there a standard way to make database changes at the time I "pull" or "push" the website files (MSSQL) or do I need to produce a separate script?**

*At this point I'm considering going manual. When i remote on to the system to pull the website manually, I can open SQL Manager and manually run the .sql scripts created as part of the update procedure.*

I understand that what I'm asking for is quite specific, so I very well may need to write my own deployment script, but at this time I'd just like to know if anyone has encountered the same issues and can offer some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: So for the part about ignoring folders it would appear that I use a .gitignore file within the folder which ignores everything except for itself, so that files on the server neither get added or deleted during the upgrade procedure.

Still working on the rest.